# Unexpected Resonance - Dual-Band Dipole

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, impedance

I tried to make a dual-band (2m/70cm) dipole this morning by following the instructions on this page: http://www.amateurradio.bz/2m-70cm_vertical_dipole_antenna.html, with the rather major significant exception of placing the antenna's elements in a groove I routed out of a 2x4 and I'm using bare #10 copper wire instead of stainless steel.

I plugged a VNA into it and the antenna's lowest SWR was ~1.09 at ~124MHz. I tried it in a couple different environments and orientations and made sure there wasn't anything conductive right near the antenna (other than the wood, which I'm expecting to reduce the effective velocity factor of the wire.

Since I have no shortage of #10 wire, I started trimming the ends in 1/2" increments. I got the lowest SWR to 1.04 at 148MHz... but only while horizontal! Orienting the antenna vertically causes the lowest SWR point to jump to 1.52 at 153MHz.

What's happening here? Why was the tuning so far off? Is it the wood? Is it the copper wire? Why does orientation affect the tuning so much? I know I've got a lot of variables here, but is there one that is obviously the most important difference?

Comment: Can you rule out common-mode current on the feedline as a factor?

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II: The entire system is: analyzer -> ~10ft of RG-8X -> antenna. 
Where would common-mode current get into that? Honest question here, because I don't know.

Comment: see http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7108/dipole-antenna-current-distribution-at-any-time-instant and http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/538/using-a-balun-with-a-resonant-dipole

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Good point. Without a suitable 1:1 balun (common-mode choke) at the feedpoint, the SWR could be affected by nearby conductive objects (such as his hands) near the coax. Even touching the VNA can affect the reading! And even with a balun, the SWR might be affected by the antenna's proximity to the earth, house wiring, and his body. Measurements would be best done outdoors with the antenna as high as possible.

Comment: I've made air-wound chokes before (ye olde coax wound around some PVC), but I'm having trouble finding any information about how baluns work for VHF and UHF; all the plans seem to say things like "works great for 1.6-30MHz".

Comment: Even with the antenna outdoors and very high, the presence of the feedline will still affect the SWR.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to measure and tune the antenna in an environment as close to the installation environment as possible? If it's not going to 30 feet up on a mast, why bother testing it there?

Comment: @William-Rem VHF baluns sound like a good topic for a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the wood!

It may *also* be the fact that I'm using copper wire instead of stainless steel rod, but I can't test that as I don't have access to any stainless.

Further experimentation this evening show much more predictable results. While I thought the 2x4 would be relatively transparent to RF, simply being near the 2x4 seems to cause the whole system to seem electrically much longer than it is, thus making the antenna very difficult to tune.

At first, I thought that it was conducting RF to the wood because the wire was bare, but I cut new elements just now out of my solid-core #10 THHN, this time leaving the THHN on everywhere except where the bolts contact the wire and had basically the same results. Bending the wire away from the wood such that the tips of the dipole (where voltage is highest?) caused the match to jump from 118MHz to 137MHz.

My best guess here is that the lumber is not fully dried and whatever water left in it is causing it to be a (poor) conductor, causing some capacitative coupling. I'd still love for anybody with more experience to chime in though, as I'm just guessing and am pretty new to making antennas.

Comment: I think you're right with the wood. Even fully dry wood has some moisture content from ambient humidity. Water is a lossy dielectric, and wood isn't a perfect insulator. The antenna can couple to it inductively and capacitively, even if it's insulated from direct contact. Copper vs stainless steel probably has negligible effect.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilFrost-W8II, for the confirmation. I'll print a bracket out of ABS soon and that should solve that.

Comment: Attaching the wire directly to the wood will not only add a little capacitive loading, it will also effectively decrease the velocity factor just as insulation will. In pure bare copper in air it can range from .90 to .97. The wood could easily be dropping it to .70 or even lower, resulting in a ~20% increase in electrical length even ignoring any loading.

Comment: "Bending the wire away from the wood such that the tips of the dipole (where voltage is highest?) caused the match to jump from 118MHz to 137MHz." This is not clear to me, and I don't see how any dry untreated wood would affect it, seeing how the feedpoint Z of a dipole is so low and only the feedpoint is touching the wood (right?). *When bending the wire away from the wood, did you also move the dipoles farther apart from each other, and/or farther away from the mast?* What is your mast material? Can you post a photo of your antenna here?

Comment: @Hamsterdave - Thanks, that does seem to account for the difference I was seeing.

Comment: @MikeWaters - I think the wood (being a simple fir 2x4) contains about 15% moisture content (according to www.clemson.edu/psapublishing/pages/fyd/HL255.pdf). It sounds like you may the wrong idea of what I was attempting, which was to place the _entire_ antenna inside the 2x4. My hope was to plane it down and paint it like the trim on my house as a stealthy aerial option.

Comment: @Mike Waters, the rf loss tangent for most cellulose based materials I can find good numbers for (including wood, paper, and phenolics) range from about  0.025 to 0.05. This is approximately 100 times more loss than typical plate glass, and >1000 times the loss of low loss dielectrics like PTFE and HDPE. Dielectric losses would also be max near the ends of the dipole where the e-field is strongest. Make the wood just a bit wet, which pine nearly always is, and it is reasonable that losses, capacitive loading,  and velocity factor could result in the 20% change in resonant freq OP observed.

Comment: @William-Rem I missed that! It all makes sense now. There's a lot of difference between the photo on that link vs. what you did. Now I understand why the wood is very likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you were standing on the ground when you tested your antenna so rotating the elements in a vertical position made them closer to the ground effectively detuning your antenna.

To avoid that, the antenna elements must be above the ground at least 1/4 of the wavelength - in your case higher than 2m / 4 = 50cm at all times.

Another factor could be your feed line. Try coiling some coax near the feed point (simple RF choke) and see if your tuning changes - http://www.k3dav.com/rfchokecoil.htm

Comment: I wasn't handholding the antenna at the time, but had set it on a non-conductive surface. When I did final tuning though, after figuring out not to put it *inside* of a 2x4, the bottom tip of the antenna (attached to the shield) was only about 20cm from the ground.

Comment: Willam - you want it higher than that above the ground to avoid detuning.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting antenna with but with no information included 
about behavior of the unique part at 70cm.

For RF insight into the design, a horizontal 2 meter dipole for 144 MHz was 
modeled using #8 copper wire at 2 meters elevation. The 70cm portion was formed by wires from the feedpoint connections going down then to the sides beneath 
the 2 meter arms.  This is an approximation of the "U" shaped elements 
described in the article.

Tuning for 144 MHz was easy. It worked out to be 19.055 inches for the 
long arms with a feedpoint separation = 1.05 inches. Total 
Width=39.16 inches.

Horizontally: SWR=1.5, Z=69 Ohms, Efficiency=77%, Gain=7.5 dBi.

Vertically: SWR=1.4, Z=68 Ohms, Efficiency=51%, Gain=2.6 dBi.

However, tuning for 446 MHz was critical and required radically different shape 
and dimensions.

Spacing between arms was much wider: 3.89 inches down 
and the length of the arms much shorter: 2.12 inches... with total width=5.29 inches.

Horizontally, the "L" shape still radiates like a dipole with a very minor vertical component.

Horizontally: SWR=1.05, Z=50 Ohms, Efficiency=73%, Gain=9.4 dBi.

Vertically: SWR=1.02, Z=51, Efficiency=60%, Gain=6.2 dBi

Note: The Z impedance of a vertical is not effected by feedpoint height.  Not so horizontally. Z goes up and down around 72 Ohms (1.4 SWR) so tuning changes with height.

Comment: Thanks for modeling this. I ended up with a kind of L shape and I'd been wondering about what kind of nonsensical radiation pattern it might have.